# configure query to bring rows which have more than 1 entries

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get those entries which have more than 1 records?

If it doesn't make sense... let me explain:

From the below table I want to access the sum of the commission of all rows where type is joining and "they have more than 1 entry with same `downmem_id`".

I have this query but it doesn't consider more entries scenario...

```
$search = "SELECT sum(commission) as income FROM `$database`.`$memcom` where type='joining'";
```

Here's the table:

```
id   mem_id   commission   downmem_id   type            time
 2      1       3250            2      joining   2019-09-22 13:24:40
 3      45      500             2      egbvegr        new time
 4      32      20              2      vnsjkdv        other time
 5      23      2222            2      vfdvfvf        some other time
 6      43      42              3      joining        time
 7      32      353             5      joining        time 
 8      54      35              5      vsdvsdd        time
```

Here's the expected result: it should be the sum of the id no 2, 7 only
ie. 3250+353=whatever.

It shouldn't include id no 6 because it has only 1 row with the same `downmem_id`.

Please help me to make this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(t.commission) income
from (select sum(case when type = 'joining' then commission end) as commission
      from t
      group by downmem_id
      having count(*) > 1
     ) t;
```

The main advantage to this approach is that this more readily supports more complex conditions on the other members of each group -- such as at most one "joining" record or both "joining" records and no more than two "vnsjkdv" records.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
select sum(t.commission) income
from tablename t
where t.type = 'joining'
and exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id <> t.id and downmem_id = t.downmem_id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2Nv2XRU17vaxBvD5eP4Sh/2).
Results:

```
| income |
| -----  |
| 3603   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery that will find all `downmem_id` having more than one occurrence in the table.

```
SELECT Sum(commission) AS income 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  type = 'joining' 
       AND downmem_id IN (SELECT downmem_id 
                          FROM   tablename t 
                          GROUP  BY downmem_id 
                          HAVING Count(id) > 1);
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2Nv2XRU17vaxBvD5eP4Sh/3)